# Display Next 'LI' in javascript - Same titled 'LI'

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript/PHP code that brings in a RSS feed in a kind of loop so I can write some code at the start and end of it.  (But I guess the text I write at the start and end will probably need to be the same each time.)

So what I really need is some javascript to hide all the other li's except the first, and only display them when the next/previous buttons are clicked. I would prefer to not use jquery as its going to be a mini 1 page app (But will accept if needs must!)

```
<img src="previous.jpg" onClick="javascript_to_go_to_previous_li">
<ul>
<li id="sameidasrest">Post 1</li>
<li id="sameidasrest">Post 2</li>
<li id="sameidasrest">Post 3</li>
<li id="sameidasrest">Post 4</li>
</ul>
<img src="next.jpg" onClick="javascript_to_go_to_next_li">
```

Any way of doing that?

Comment: You should change the li's from having id's to classes. id's are unique and as such your markup is invalid and can have different results depending on browser.

Comment: Being a mini one page app is not justification for not using jQuery. jQuery is light weight and makes this 10 times easier and quicker.

Comment: We need justification for *not* using jQuery now?

Comment: @ithcy: You make a good point. Still, flem managed to justify _not not_ using it, in the end.

Comment: *"But will accept if needs must!"*: jQuery is never a must. Everything that jQuery offers can be done without it, even if it's a lot more complicated. It's just a library after all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true, if the OP wasn't a self-confessed noob, I'd probably agree. But I think when the problem is as easy as this, a new coder should first learn how to solve it without any libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, you should really use an identifier for your `<ul>` element. Then, you can't use the same ID for all your `<li>` elements. Every element has to have its own ID or, even better, you can use a combination of HTML + CSS + JavaScript to reach your goal.

```
HTML:
<ul id="myList" class="collapsed">
  <li>Post 1</li>
  <li>Post 2</li>
  <li>Post 3</li>
  <li>Post 4</li>
</ul>
<button id="btnTest">Click Me</button>

CSS:
ul.collapsed li:first-child {
  display:block;
}

ul.collapsed li {
  display:none;
}

JS:
document.getElementById('btnTest').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var list = document.getElementById('myList'),
      classes = list.className;
  if ( /collapsed/.test( classes ) ) {
    list.className = classes.replace( 'collapsed', '' );
  } else {
    list.className = classes + ' collapsed';
  }
});
```

You can test it at http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/ZafdC/

In this example I define the list and a button. The button works like a switch. Every time you click it, the list shows and hides the elements. All simply adding and removing a CSS class from the `<ul>` element.

Alternatively, you can use some framework such as jQuery, and in this case you can change the JS above in:

```
$('#btnTest').on('click', function(){
  $('#myList').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

The code to test it at http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/cUYPq/

---

This example is to interactively show/hide single list items using HTML+CSS and bare JavaScript:

```
HTML:
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="show">Post 1</li>
  <li class="hide">Post 2</li>
  <li class="hide">Post 3</li>
  <li class="hide">Post 4</li>
</ul>

<button id="btnShowOne">Show Item</button>
<button id="btnHideOne">Hide Item</button>

CSS:
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

JS:
function iterateAndToggleClass( elements, classNameFind, classNameReplace, isTopDown ) {
  if ( isTopDown ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
      var element = elements[i];
      if ( element.className === classNameFind ) {
        element.className = classNameReplace;
        return;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for ( var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
      var element = elements[i];
      if ( element.className === classNameFind ) {
        element.className = classNameReplace;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('btnShowOne').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();

  var list = document.getElementById('myList'),
      items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

  iterateAndToggleClass( items, 'hide', 'show', true );
});

document.getElementById('btnHideOne').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();

  var list = document.getElementById('myList'),
      items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

  iterateAndToggleClass( items, 'show', 'hide', false );
});
```

Of course this is not optimized code, but I hope it's clear enough. You can test it at http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/swGEY/

Comment: Please include the code in your answer as well. If jsfiddle is unreachable for any reason, your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Thats cool. But just displays every other     <li> except the one that is visible. Not just the next one. Though I get your point I should identify the     <ul> not the     <il>

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your request. Well if you need to interactively  display the `<li>` elements one by one, you can simply get a list of all the items to iterate. When you click the button/link, you iterate the list to find the first available hidden element, then remove the class that hides it and terminate the iteration (and the opposite to hide the items). I know, maybe it's a bit hard to understand explained in this way, so if you need I can edit my answer to better explain this with an example.

Comment: @Ragnarokkr I literally would love that. I have spent all evening searching this problem. Your JS Fiddles were cool :)

Comment: @user1978360 I added the code and a link so you can test it directly on jsFiddle. Please note that this example works on every recent browser, but if you need compatibility with IE, you will have to adjust the code so that the event could be attached correctly according to IE's DOM specifics